# Десерериализовать список данных JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json

Необходимо десериализовать список данных в модель вот такого типа

```
[
{
    "value1": "zzz",
    "value2": "qwe",
},
{
    "value1": "111",
    "value2": "yyy",
},
]
```

Модель

```
public class Test
{
public string value1 { get; set; }
public string value2 { get; set; }
}
var valueData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IReadOnlyList<Test>>(stringValue);
```

При десериализации вываливается ошибка, я так понимаю из за того что так ожидается анонимный массив? Как правильно задать модель для преобразования?

Comment: Почему вы в `IReadOnlyList` пытаетесь запихнуть? Попробуйте просто `List<>`.

Answer (score 2):

Вы хотяб ошибку давали, которую вам пишет, ибо пока не запустить - фиг поймешь.

Вам ошибка говорит следующее:

> The JSON object contains a trailing comma at the end which is not supported in this mode.

Это означает то, что в вашем JSON есть так называемые ["Висящие запятые" (Trailing commas)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas), это все те запятые, которые находятся в конце последних объектов.

```
[
   {
      "value1":"zzz",
      "value2":"qwe", 
                   ^^^   
   },
   {
      "value1":"111",
      "value2":"yyy",
                   ^^^    
   },
   ^^^
]
```

Некоторые библиотеки по умолчанию отключают возможность использования подобных запятых и выносят эту опцию в настройки, Microsoft в своей новоиспеченной `System.Text.Json` не исключение.

У вас есть по сути 3 варианта:

1. Убрать из JSON строки все висящие запятые.
2. Переопределить настройки:

   ```
   var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
   {
       AllowTrailingCommas = true
   };
   var valueData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IReadOnlyList<Test>>(stringValue, options);
   ```
3. Использовать другую библиотеку для работы с JSON (например `Newtonsoft.Json` по умолчанию разрешает использовать такие запятые).